# Temporary CUDA Device Arrays

Tags: c++, cuda

Having been playing around with this grand CUDA experiment for a few months now, I find myself experimenting more and trying to pull away from the tutorial examples.

My question is this : If I want to just use arrays on the GPU for something like temporary storage without copying them back to the host for display/output, can I just create a device array with `__device__ double array[numpoints];`  Then for anything I want to take back from the GPU, I need to do the whole cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy spiel, right?  Additionally, is there any difference between one method or another? I thought they both create arrays in global memory.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) discription about the `__device__` qualifier. So if you declare it `__device__` you cannot access it in the host through `cudaMemcpy` but there are other mentioned in the link.

Instead what you can do is declare a global pointer(ie., without `__device__`) in **host code** and allocate using the `cudaMalloc`. So you can use the same to copy the result back to host using the `cudaMemcpy`.

Comment: cudaMemcpy can be used to copy to statically declared `__device__` memory. That is what `cudaGetSymbolAddress` and `cudaGetSymbolSize` are for -- you can get details of static symbols at runtime and then use them just like any other host address.

Comment: @talonmies : Good to know this. Just tried and it works thank you. If you would answer the same I would upvote it (it looks like this is what the poster of the question is looking for).

Answer (score 1):

You can create, fill and use globl memory arrays without the need of using `cudaMemcpy` to copy data from the host for initialization, if this is what are you asking. In the following simple example, I'm creating a global memory array which is initialized directly on the device and then I'm releasing it when not needed anymore.

```
#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void init_temp_data(float* temp_data) {
    temp_data[threadIdx.x] = 3.f;
}

__global__ void copy_global_data(float* temp_data, float* d_data) {
    d_data[threadIdx.x] = temp_data[threadIdx.x];
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

int main() {

    float* data = (float*)malloc(16*sizeof(float));
    float* d_data; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data,16*sizeof(float)));
    float* temp_data; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&temp_data,16*sizeof(float)));

    init_temp_data<<<1,16>>>(temp_data);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 

    copy_global_data<<<1,16>>>(temp_data,d_data);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 

    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(temp_data));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(data,d_data,16*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) printf("Element number %i is equal to %f\n",i,data[i]);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```